# Can not find symbol setClickListener

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set an onlclick listener to a recycleview in an android app but I keep getting the above error in the IDE despite doing everything correctly.

Here is he complete code for the DrinksActivity class showing how I am trying to add the clickListener

```
    public class DrinksActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnItemClickListener {
//recyclerview object
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

//adapter object
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter;

//database reference
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

//progress dialog
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//list to hold all the uploaded images
private List<Upload> uploads;
TableLayout item;
Menu menu;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drinks);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    item = findViewById(R.id.item);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    uploads = new ArrayList<>();

    //displaying progress dialog while fetching images
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Items Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);
    Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("category").equalTo("Ecohim");


    //adding an event listener to fetch values
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            //dismissing the progress dialog
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            //iterating through all the values in database
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploads.add(upload);
            }
            //creating adapter
            adapter = new ItemsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), uploads);

            //adding adapter to recyclerview
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.setClickListener(ItemsAdapter.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
    setBadgeCount(this, icon, "9");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(id == R.id.action_check_out){

    }
    else if(id == R.id.action_clear_cart){
        MenuItem itemCart = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        LayerDrawable icon = (LayerDrawable) itemCart.getIcon();
        setBadgeCount(this, icon, "9");

    }
    else{
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_drinks) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DrinksActivity.class));
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_seeds) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, DrinksActivity.class));
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
public static void setBadgeCount(Context context, LayerDrawable icon, String count) {

    BadgeDrawable badge;

    // Reuse drawable if possible
    Drawable reuse = icon.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge);
    if (reuse != null && reuse instanceof BadgeDrawable) {
        badge = (BadgeDrawable) reuse;
    } else {
        badge = new BadgeDrawable(context);
    }

    badge.setCount(count);
    icon.mutate();
    icon.setDrawableByLayerId(R.id.ic_badge, badge);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter Your Email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

And here is the ItemsAdapter class file where the method setClickListener is found

```
    public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Upload> uploads;
private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

            return  viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());
    holder.textdescription.setText(upload.getDescription());
    holder.textcost.setText( "Ksh" + upload.getCost());
    Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return uploads.size();
}
public void setClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView textViewName, textdescription, textcost;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
        textcost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textcost);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this); // bind the listener
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition()); // call the onClick in the OnItemClickListener
    }
}
}
```

Finally this Is the OnItemClickListener Interface code

```
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
void onClick(View view, int position);}
```

I have removed all the imports and the package declaration lines to make the code shorter.
What could I be doing wrong and how can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: can you explain what do you want to achieve? I am aware that you put a lot of effort trying to find a solution

Comment: What is the declared typed for variable 'adapter' for which you are trying to call setClickListener?

Comment: Is your code compiling? From what I see, you should be getting an error for passing an instance of `ValueEventListener`  to `adapter.setClickListener();` by passing `this` to it.

Comment: @maheryhaja I want to set an onclick listener to a recycle view item so that I can add the clicked item to cart

Comment: @TeemuLätti here is the declaration  private  `RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;`

Comment: @codeConscious the error of can not find symbol setClickListener wont let it compile but if I remove that everything works just fine

Comment: What is signature of the activity, which has `onCreate` above?

Comment: @codeConscious what do you mean by signature all the classes are public

Comment: I wanted to ask about the interfaces your activity implemented. Your edit, now does provide that information on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176382/discussion-between-otema-and-codeconscious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your itemsAdapter class code to this

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
private Context context;
private List<Upload> uploads;
Menu menu;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);
public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");
    final Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());
    holder.textdescription.setText(upload.getDescription());
    holder.textcost.setText( "Ksh" + upload.getCost());
    holder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on: " + uploads.get(position));
            //add what you want done when the button clicked here
            });
    Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return uploads.size();
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView textViewName, textdescription, textcost;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public Button buy;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
        textcost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textcost);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addToCart);
        }
    }
}
```

That should get you sorted.
Note that I have added the onclick listener to your addToCart button that I got in your DrinksActivity class.

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty close to solving the problem. You did well on the activity side. And your way of thinking is correct.

The problem is your way of translating onItemClickedListener to OnClickListener.

First you should rename(by refactor) your custom ViewHolder since it can lead to confusion. (*optional*)

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

Rename to:

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
```

Next, don't implement directly onClickListener, just a setter is fine:

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView textViewName, textdescription, textcost;
public ImageView imageView;

//save itemview
private View itemView;

public void ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
    textcost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textcost);

    //assign itemView
    this.itemView = itemView;
    imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    //don't set listener here
}

//create a setter method 
public setHolderClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
      itemView.setOnClickListener(listener);

}

}
```

Finally we'll use a simple closure to transfer position to onItemClickListener:

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
...
@Override
//I used renamed ViewHolder
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());
    holder.textdescription.setText(upload.getDescription());
    holder.textcost.setText( "Ksh" + upload.getCost());
    Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    //assign listener here:
    holder.setHolderClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //this is the place where you should call this and everything works ;) 
             clickListener.onClick(v,position);
        }
    };

}

}
```

the final Adapter class:

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Upload> uploads;
private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
    this.uploads = uploads;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return  viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Upload upload = uploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());
    holder.textdescription.setText(upload.getDescription());
    holder.textcost.setText( "Ksh" + upload.getCost());
    Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

    //assign listener here:
    holder.setHolderClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //this is the place where you should call this and everything works ;)
            clickListener.onClick(v,position);
        }
    };

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return uploads.size();
}
public void setClickListener(OnItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
}


public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView textViewName, textdescription, textcost;
    public ImageView imageView;

    //save itemview
    private View itemView;

    public void CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textdescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdescription);
        textcost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textcost);

        //assign itemView
        this.itemView = itemView;
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        //don't set listener here
       }

    //create a setter method
    public void setHolderClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        itemView.setOnClickListener(listener);

    }
  }
}
```

**IMPORTANT**: make sure to import your OnItemClickListener

*NB* :This is the just a way to solve the problem. you can also use lambda expressions, custom interfaces, event bus or reactive streams. Hope it will help you :D

Comment: This gives me two error
1. There is no default constructor in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder
2. can not resolve method setHolderClickListener

Comment: 1. i only add few things to onBindViewHolder, keep everything else as it was in your post.

Comment: 2. make sure you use right ViewHolder, I strongly suggest to rename to CustomViewHolder because there are two kind of ViewHolder of the same name. but if you don't rename, make sure you use public void onBindViewHolder(ItemAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position)

Comment: Would you mind sharing your enrire edited file coz there seam to be some methods that you have moved and I am not able to track all of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176398/discussion-between-maheryhaja-and-otema).

Answer (score 1):

Change the declaration of the adapter in your `DrinkActivity` to

`private ItemsAdapter adapter;`

I don't know why you have declared two adapters, one should do it.

and then call `setClickListener` through this adapter

```
adapter.setClickListener(DrinkActivity.this);
```

OR

edit `adapter.setClickListener` line to this

```
((ItemsAdapter)adapter).setClickListener(DrinkActivity.this)
```

Comment: That gives the error can not resolve symbol setClickListener(DrinkActivity

Comment: The first option gives me an error at the ItemsAdapter can not resolve method onClick()